# How to fix Duplicate Compile Items Included error for console application in VS2019?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Every time I create a new Net Core console project ("Hello world") or a class library and add a new class, I get the NETSDK1022 error ("duplicated compile items"). I have already reinstalled Visual Studio 2019, probably deleted all possible files and imported the configuration from a properly functioning VS installation on another computer. In this case, nothing helps. When I add a new class then Visual Studio adds a section to the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include = "Class1.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

which causes the error. If I delete it, the project will compile correctly. But I have to do this after adding each new class. In other VS installations, this section is not added. Why in this case VS adds this section? What settings can cause this? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Is your visual studio up to date?

Comment: As fresh as possible - removed and installed today. I've installed it on another computer and it works there. But on my machine it does not.

Comment: After uninstalling, I also manually removed all files that could be related to visual studio, including nuget and template files. I also cleaned the registry. But apparently I missed something since the same problem appears again in the new installation.

Comment: Delete that project reference and it should just work, if I understand the problem ans thr Cs file is under thr same directory

Comment: I can manually edit any project and it will work. But my point is not to do it, since it works on other computers. Clarifying the problem - what to do so that VS does not add the "Compile include" item to the project file when I add a class, because it does not do it on other computers.

Comment: You need to add a using statement for each reference/project you add.  The using statement is the namespace of the root of the reference.  So when you have at top of module "using System"  there is a Net library with the root namespace System.